# Correct way to use UITableViewController

Tags: swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var renderWidth:CGFloat = 8
    var renderYPosition:CGFloat = 22
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("idcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    let date = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(renderWidth, renderYPosition, 110, 20))
    let dateText = "asdasdasdsad"
    date.text = dateText
    if(cell.selected){
        date.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
    cell.addSubview(date)
    renderWidth = renderWidth + 110
}
```

If i have three type of rows to display,(e.g, radio button, text label, text view), the index path of showing these rows are completely dynamic. So i add some if case in cellForRowAtIndexPath to determine which type of row it should display. And i will use addsubview to do that. However, i have seen some post mentioned that we should not add subview in cellForRowAtIndexPath. i can't get it. And whats the alternative to that? what is the correct way to do that??

Comment: Create 3 prototype cells with unique ID's and then just dequeue the one you want.

Comment: but why i shouldn't do that by adding subview in this function?

Comment: Since cells are reused, if you add subviews you have to take care to remove those subviews when the cell is reused if it is a different type.  It's easier just to have 3 cells configured as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Reusable cells should be identical - so in your case you should make three different cell models, and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` have your logic figure out which one you want to dequeue (make sure you register the cell in the tableview first). This way you don't have to add subviews and you can configure the cell however you need to. This is the cleaner way to do it (also maybe look into configuring a cell with a viewmodel).